# Can I Use Delete Item Action using SharePoint Designer 2013 to delete items from different list

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-online, sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-server, sharepoint-foundation

Here I am working on SharePoint designer 2013  list workflow and have two lists where on adding an item to the list A in Title column, it would delete the items with the same name from List B title column. It would remove the duplicate Names even in the List B if it contains the same name

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Keep in Mind**, The `Delete Item` action is terminated on the computer running the `Workflow Manager workflow engine` and throws a `System.InvalidOperationException` exception.

For more details check [Workflow actions quick reference (SharePoint Workflow platform)](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/general-development/workflow-actions-quick-reference-sharepoint-workflow-platform)

**Unfortunately,** There is no workaround for this exception!! Meanwhile, you can go through the below alternatives/workarounds

---

**Alternatives**

- Create a SharePoint 2010 workflow to Use `Delete Item` Action and run it from the SharePoint 2013 Workflow.

[image]

- Using a 3rd party tool like `Nintix`.
- Develop a custom workflow using VS.
- Develop an `Event Receiver` to delete a specific list item in a specific list onItemAdded in the main list based on your criteria.